# Introduce previously proved theorem as hypothesis

Tags: coq

Suppose that I have already proved some theorem in coq, and later I want to introduce it as a hypothesis in the proof of another theorem. Is there a succinct way to do this?

The need for this typically arises for me when I want to do something like a proof by cases. And I've discovered that one way to do this is to `assert` the statement of the theorem, and then immediately prove it, but this seems kind of cumbersome. For example I tend to write things like:

```
Require Import Arith.EqNat.

Definition Decide P := P \/ ~P.

Theorem decide_eq_nat: forall x y: nat, Decide (x = y).
Proof.
  intros x y. remember (beq_nat x y) as b eqn:E. destruct b.
    left. apply beq_nat_eq. assumption.
    right. apply beq_nat_false. symmetry. assumption. Qed.

Theorem silly: forall x y: nat, x = y \/ x <> y.
Proof.
  intros x y.
  assert (Decide (x = y)) as [E|N] by apply decide_eq_nat.
    left. assumption.
    right. assumption. Qed.
```

But is there an easier way than having to type the whole `assert [statement] by apply [theorem]` thing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `pose proof theorem_name as X.`, where `X` is the name you want to introduce.

---

If you're going to destruct it right away, you can also: `destruct (decide_eq_nat x y).`