# Best way to perform universal instantiation in Coq

Tags: coq, quantifiers

Suppose I have an hypothesis `H : forall ( x : X ), P x` and a variable `x : X` in the context. I want to perform universal instantiation and obtain a new hypothesis `H' : P x`. What is the most painless way to do this? Apparently `apply H in x` does not work. `assert ( P x )` followed by `apply H` does, but it can get very messy if `P` is complex.

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905182/introduce-previously-proved-theorem-as-hypothesis?rq=1) that seems somewhat related. Not sure if it can be applied here, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pose proof (H x) as H'.`

The parentheses are optional.

Answer (score 3):

If you want new hypothesis you can use @Ptival's answer, or

```
assert (H' := H x).
```

If it is ok to substitute existing hypothesis

```
specialize (H x).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `generalize (H x); intros Hx`: `generalize` will add `(H x)` as a new implication in front of the current goal, and `intros` will put it in your hypotheses.